# How to approach microfrontends in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, microservices, micro-frontend

I'm fairly new to microservices and web development, but built myself a small microservice architecture in ASP.NET where I have a few services with simple CRUD operations exposed by a REST api. Currently I can consume them in a single MVC client and render the views with the data from the microservices via model binding.

What I'm trying to achieve now is to make the frontend of each service independent as well, but I struggle to figure out how. By my understanding each service must have it's own views and somehow make these available to the client.
But how do I handle model binding in the .cshtml like I currently do in the client in that case?

I've tried to read up on the topic but fail to find an entry point.

Is there example of a microfrontend implementation in ASP.NET (not core) anywhere?

Comment: I am looking for the same. Is there a way I can use microfront end in my partial view.

Answer (score 2):

Services are just services, and you use them expose data to one or many applications. Which have access to the services typically by using authentication of some sort. You **do not** want to have views tied into the micro service. Because then you're just making an MVC type app and calling it a micro service, which is ok but not a micro service.

Think of services as having one main purpose to send and receive data, like a *User* service. Your front-end will call that service to get data about a user, update a user, create a user, etc. Each service is different, and one view can access many services.

See links for more details:

- [What are micro services](https://aws.amazon.com/microservices/)
- [micro service architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/architecture-styles/microservices)
- [microservice-application-design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/microservice-application-design)
- [Microservice using ASP NET Core](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1276639/Microservice-using-ASP-NET-Core)

So you'll want to make your front-end with the framework/stach of choice, like Blazor/MVC 5/Vue/Angular/React/etc and have that front-end code call the services you're making via HTTP requests.

*edit based on comments:*

In the same vein you'll also want to make sure that your front-end application(s) follow a similar approach. You want to avoid a massive monolithic front-end by building an array of smaller and to-the-point applications.

For example, you could have a giant application that handles: meetings, calendars, appointments, trip planning, users, and customers. OR, you could take the micro service approach and build each feature out into its own independently deploy-able application. So you will have meetings app, a calendar app, a users app, etc. Each application is it's own entity but uses the services you have, so you get separation for loose coupling allowing for scalability, and the other pros that come along with micro service architecture, in your front-end.

see [here](https://martinfowler.com/articles/micro-frontends.html) for more details on a micro front-end.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Based on this figure by microsoft it is possible to implement microservices that compose a viewModel though:


https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/architecture/microservices/architect-microservice-container-applications/media/microservice-based-composite-ui-shape-layout/microservice-generate-composite-ui.png


I'm looking for a way to implement such a microservice.

Comment: That view model will live in your front-end project. Like in Blazor or MVC you'd want to make a view model for each view. You'd populate that model with a Service class that access your API/micro service.

Comment: If it clarifies better, the micro service does not produce or use a view model at all. That's done in the front-end application. What is your front-end in? We could help you make a view model for it, but your micro service won't be what does that.

Comment: But that would lead to a monolithic frontend again? I currently got a monolithic frontend in MVC. What I am trying to achieve are microfrontends though, where each service delivers its own UI.

Comment: Actually what you are asking for would make your service and front-end into a monolith application. What you should do is have multiple front-end applications, in your case several MVC ones, and multiple services that power them. The key is to keep the services and front-end separate from each other, and to build multiple apps vs a single monolith.

Comment: Based on your edit, lets say I have a calendar and a meetings app, but now I'd like to display both on the same web page or at least have a common frame around them and be able to switch between them. How would I approach that? I assume integrate them with javascript somehow?

Comment: Since you already have the services in place you can make view components to see "meetings" or "calendars" on a single page or within tabs, etc. Alternatively you wouldn't separate those applications out at all, because it does make sense to have them in the same application.

Comment: What you want to do is separate your application out into separate logical chunks that make sense. Say you had an order processing app that also made content for a blog. That would make sense to have those as separate applications. Does that help answer your question?

Comment: I see. View Components are something I read up on, but sadly only become available in ASP.NET Core and not in ASP.NET. Do you have an idea on an implementation in ASP.NET?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208586/discussion-between-coderlee-and-bernd-schlowski).